# Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject

Tags: apex, trigger

I was trying to make my hands dirty with the apex coding as I am really really weak in that.
Below is the piece of Code I wrote which is getting called by a trigger(following the best practices). However I am getting this really frustrating error:

> **Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject**

Here's my sceranio:

I want to retrieve a perticular record from the custom metadata type(Client_Settings__mdt) and fill in the remaining values in my layout automatically before the record gets saved.
Below are my code snipets
Trigger:

```
trigger ScoreCostSavings on SCORE_Cost_Savings__c (before insert,before update,before delete,
                            after insert,after update,after delete) {

    //check if this is before trigger or after trigger
    SCORE_Cost_Savings__c[] scs = Trigger.new;
    ScoreCodeFrameworkUtil scfu = new ScoreCodeFrameworkUtil();

    if(Trigger.isbefore){
        if(Trigger.isInsert){
        //Code that would fire before any record is inserted
        scfu.updID(scs);
        }
        else if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        //Code that would fire before any record is updated
        scfu.updID(scs);
        }
        else if(Trigger.isDelete){
        //Code that would fire before any record is deleted
        }
    }
    else{
        if(Trigger.isInsert){
        //Code that would fire after any record is updated
        }
        else if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        //Code that would fire after any record is updated
        }
        else if(Trigger.isDelete){
        //Code that would fire after any record is deleted
        }
    }
}
```

and here goes the Class:

```
public class ScoreCodeFrameworkUtil{
    private Integer count;

    public void updID(SCORE_Cost_Savings__c[] scrdta){
        //SCORE_Client_Settings__mdt[] scsm = [SELECT MasterLabel,Program_Framework__c,Sub_Program_Framework__c FROM SCORE_Client_Settings__mdt];
        List<SCORE_Client_Settings__mdt> scsm = [SELECT MasterLabel,NamespacePrefix,Program_Framework__c,Sub_Program_Framework__c FROM SCORE_Client_Settings__mdt where MasterLabel =: scrdta.Code__c Limit 1];

        if(!scsm.isEmpty()){
            //scsm[0].First_Name__c = billing.billingfirstname;
            scrdta.Program_Framework__c = scsm[0].Program_Framework__c;
        }
    }
}
```

Error line:

> List scsm = [SELECT MasterLabel,NamespacePrefix,Program_Framework__c,Sub_Program_Framework__c FROM SCORE_Client_Settings__mdt where MasterLabel =: scrdta.Code__c Limit 1];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the incoming parameter for the function is array and you are referencing a field directly from the array which is not allowed  .

The below shows the approach of using loops on array and then using property to access the values

```
public void updID(SCORE_Cost_Savings__c[] scrdta){
    set<String> setscrdtaCodes = new set<String> ();
    for(SCORE_Cost_Savings__c sCode :scrdta){
        setscrdtaCodes.add(sCode.Code__c);
    }
    List<SCORE_Client_Settings__mdt> scsm = [SELECT MasterLabel,NamespacePrefix,Program_Framework__c,Sub_Program_Framework__c FROM SCORE_Client_Settings__mdt where MasterLabel IN : setscrdtaCodes Limit 1];

    if(!scsm.isEmpty()){
        //scsm[0].First_Name__c = billing.billingfirstname;
        scrdta.Program_Framework__c = scsm[0].Program_Framework__c;
    }
}
```

If you want single reference from the array then you can use below

```
public void updID(SCORE_Cost_Savings__c[] scrdta){
List<SCORE_Client_Settings__mdt> scsm = [SELECT MasterLabel,NamespacePrefix,Program_Framework__c,Sub_Program_Framework__c FROM SCORE_Client_Settings__mdt where MasterLabel =: scrdta[0]. Limit 1];

 if(!scsm.isEmpty()){
    //scsm[0].First_Name__c = billing.billingfirstname;
    scrdta.Program_Framework__c = scsm[0].Code__c;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't **get** or **set** a field on a collection.

Proper Get:

```
Set<String> codes = new Set<String>();
for (Score_Cost_Savings__c record : scrdta)
    codes.add(record.Code__c);
List<SCORE_Client_Settings__mdt> metadata = [
    SELECT ... FROM SCORE_Client_Settings__mdt
    WHERE MasterLabel IN :codes LIMIT 1
];
```

Proper Set:

```
for (Score_Client_Settings__c record : scrdata)
    record.Program_Framework__c = metadata[0].Program_Framework__c
```